# Segmentation fault: 11 Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

My code worked fine on in Xcode 9.x.x. But not worked in Xcode 10. I am getting compile time error. My code like this:

```
protocol A {

}

protocol B {
    associatedtype T: A
    func b(p: T)
}

class L<P>: A {

}

class C<K, O: L<K>>: B {
    func b(p: O) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your title says you have a segmentation fault which is a runtime error but your question says you have a compile time error. Which is it? If you have a runtime error, show code that actually causes the error.

Comment: I checked, and the code Shohin provided does cause the Swift compiler to crash with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's a bug in the Swift compiler. (Any time a build fails and there's a crash report instead of an error message, it's a bug.) Please file it with either [Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) or [Swift open source](https://bugs.swift.org), and *please* include your very nice reduced test case, which will save somebody hours of work!